# H2o Package not found Scala Sparkling Water

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

I am trying to run **Sparkling Water** on my Local instance of Spark 2.1.0.
I followed documentation on [H2o](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/sparkling-water/rel-2.1/0/index.html) for Sparling Water. But when I try to execute

```
sparkling-shell.cmd
```

I am getting following error :

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I look into the batch file and I am getting this error when the following command is executed:

```
C:\Users\Mansoor\libs\spark\spark-2.1.0/bin/spark-shell.cmd --jars C:\Users\Mansoor\libs\H2o\sparkling\bin\../assembly/build/libs/sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.1.0-all.jar --driver-memory 3G --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=384m"
```

When I remove `--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=384m"`, Spark starts but I am unable to import the packages of H2o.

```
import org.apache.spark.h2o._
```

> error: object h2o is not a member of package org.apache.spark

I tried everything I could but unable to solve this issue. Could someone help me in this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `spark-shell` command while submitting jars. Workaround is to modify **spark-defaults.conf**

Adding `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` parameters to **spark-defaults.conf** file as follows:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath    \path\to\jar\sparkling-water-assembly_version>-all.jar

spark.executor.extraClassPath   \path\to\jar\sparkling-water-assembly_version>-all.jar
```

And Remove `--jars  \path\to\jar\sparkling-water-assembly_version>-all.jar` from **sparkling-shell2.cmd**

Answer (score 1):

Please try to correct your path:

`C:\Users\Mansoor\libs\spark\spark-2.1.0/bin/spark-shell.cmd --jars C:\Users\Mansoor\libs\H2o\sparkling\bin\..\assembly\build\libs\sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.1.0-all.jar --driver-memory 3G --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=384m"`

There is also doc page about RSparkling at Windows, which can contain different troubleshooting tips...
https://github.com/h2oai/sales-engineering/tree/master/megan/RSparklingAndWindows